# I print a tuple on its own, but not with other variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am an experienced `c` programmer trying to come to terms with `Python`.

`location` is `tuple` and I can print with the following

```
print(" %s %s" % (date_time, model))
print("Lat: %-.4f, Lon: %-.4f" % (location))
```

I tried to combine this into a single print, but get error `TypeError: must be real number, not tuple` with the following

```
print("%s %s Lat: %-.4f, Lon: %-.4f" % (date_time, model, location))
```

I have tried several variations, without success.

I can think of several ways of working around this (which I would do if I had to deliver a working program) but would like to understand an elegant method an experienced Python programmer would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack your tuple.

```
>>> date_time, model, location = 1, 2, (3, 4)
>>> print("%s %s Lat: %-.4f, Lon: %-.4f" % (date_time, model, *location))
1 2 Lat: 3.0000, Lon: 4.0000
```

[pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/) is a helpful site that summarizes string formatting in Python.

In general, I suggest the usage of the new-style `str.format` over the `%` operator. [Here's](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) the relevant PEP.

Answer (score 2):

You want to print the values **in** the tuple, not the tuple itself. Either concatenate the tuple:

```
print("%s %s Lat: %-.4f, Lon: %-.4f" % ((date_time, model) + location)))
```

or interpolate the tuple values into the first tuple:

```
print("%s %s Lat: %-.4f, Lon: %-.4f" % (date_time, model, *location))
```

Personally, I'd not use printf formatting here *at all*. Use the more modern and powerful [string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), preferably in the form of the (very fast) [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f"{date_time} {model} Lat: {location[0]:-.4f}, Lon: {location[1]:-.4f}")
```